# Excel VBA With statement returning type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I have created some VBA code to take populated data from a spreadsheet called "Horizontal Data" and paste it into a worksheet called "master plan data", however the with Workbooks(wb1) is throwing a type mismatch error, is there anything wrong I am doing here?

```
Dim WBA as Variant    
Dim WB1, WB2 As Workbook
Dim L As Long

Set WB2 = ThisWorkbook

MsgBox "Select Master Plan File"
WBA = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                 FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLSX), *.XLSX", _
                 Title:="Select Master Plan File")
If WBA = False Then
MsgBox "You have not selected a file"
Exit Sub
End If
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(WBA)

WB2.Activate
With Worksheets("Master Plan Data")
      .Rows("2:100000").Clear
End With


'ERROR BEGINS HERE
With Workbooks(WB1)  '  <-- Getting Type Mismatch here
    Worksheets("HORIZONTAL_DATA").Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
End With
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Workbooks` object can certainly be used for finding a workbook. However, it requires either a numeric index or the workbook name itself:

```
Workbooks(42)
Workbooks("paxsheet.xls")
```

You already *have* the workbook you want to play with, it's in `WB1`, so you don't need to go looking for it.

So change:

```
With Workbooks(WB1)  '  <-- Getting type mismatch here '
```

into:

```
With WB1             '  <-- Should not get type mismatch here '
```

and all should be well.

---

And, *beyond* that immediate error, since you want to use the worksheets *within* that workbook, you need to specify that by prefixing it with `.`:

```
With WB1
    .Worksheets("HORIZONTAL_DATA").Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
End With
```

Further, assuming you don't need the selection to be maintained other than for that copy, you can directly copy it *without* first selecting:

```
With WB1
    .Worksheets("HORIZONTAL_DATA").Cells.Copy
End With
```

But, of course, then it becomes pretty useless to even use the `with`, so you may want to just simplify the whole thing to:

```
WB1.Worksheets("HORIZONTAL_DATA").Cells.Copy
```

Comment: The first internal line should be prefixed with a period and `.Copy` could be directly applied. `.Worksheets("HORIZONTAL_DATA").Cells.Copy`

Comment: Good point, @Jeeped, I've incorporated that into an addendum. Of course, that seems to make the entire `with` a bit superfluous :-)

Comment: That did it! Thank you :)

My next challenge will come in the form of another question, but I might post it here.

Comment: You should change Worksheet.Cells to Worksheet.UsedRange, otherwise you're copying a ton of blank cells.

Comment: @Tmdean, it may well be they _want_ the blank cells. Perhaps they're overwriting data in the next paste. I incorporated Jeeped's suggestion since it involved an actual error but the question was really only to do with the type mismatch so I'm loathe to keep adding suggestions that may or may not be suitable for this specific question. Still, it's a good point to leave in a comment.